# How do I upload files through a CreateView using an inline formset?

Tags: python, django

I can't get files to upload through a CreateView using inline formset.

Ideally, it would be multiple files similar to how it behaves in the admin page, but at this point, I'm trying to get at least one up. In the following example, one Workshop should be able to have multiple files.

When uploading, everything saves except the file of course

## models.py

```
...


class Workshop (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

...

def upload_workshop_file_loc(instance, filename):
    slug = instance.workshop.slug
    if not slug:
        slug = unique_slug_generator(instance.workshop)
    location = "workshop/{}/".format(slug)
    return location + filename


class WorkshopFile(models.Model):
    workshop = models.ForeignKey(Workshop, related_name='files', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=upload_workshop_file_loc,
        null=True,
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator
(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'ppt'])]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file.name)

...
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Workshop, WorkshopFile
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory


class AddWorkshopForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Workshop
        exclude = []


FileFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Workshop,
WorkshopFile,
fields=['workshop','name', 'file'],
exclude=[], 
extra=1, 
can_delete=True
)
```

Most likely the culprit

## views.py

```
...
class AddWorkshopView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Workshop
    form_class = AddWorkshopForm
    template_name = "modules/add-workshop.html"
    success_url = "/modules/workshop-list/"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AddWorkshopForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        workshop = form.save(commit=False)
        workshop.save()
        workshop.created_by = request.user
        return redirect('modules:workshop', workshop.slug)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(AddWorkshopView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['files'] = FileFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['files'] = FileFormSet()
        return data


    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        files = context['files']

        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()

        if files.is_valid():
            files.instance = self.object
            files.save()

        return super(AddWorkshopView, self).form_valid(form)
...
```

## add-workshop.html

```
...
  <div>
    <form method="post" action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form | crispy }}
      <hr/>
        <div>
        {{ files | crispy }}
        </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md float-left" value="Save" />
    </form>
  </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not override `post` method - it's calling `form_valid` behind the scene, so it's not actually handling form. Another thing is that your `FileFormSet` is not getting `request.FILES` - that's why form for files is not processing it.

views.py:

```py
class AddWorkshopView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Workshop
    form_class = AddWorkshopForm
    template_name = "modules/add-workshop.html"
    success_url = "/modules/workshop-list/"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(AddWorkshopView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['files'] = FileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['files'] = FileFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        files = context['files']

        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()

            if files.is_valid():
                files.instance = self.object
                files.save()

        return super(AddWorkshopView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, upload the images to s3 via CreateView and without Formset. I hope this will help someone who looking for this kinda scenario.

```
from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import (BSModalCreateView)
from vcweb.settings import base
from .forms import InputForm
from utils import upload_to_s3 #global method for upload files to s3
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone

curdatetime = datetime.now(tz=get_current_timezone())
curdatetime=(str(curdatetime)).replace('-','_').replace('+','_').replace('.','_')
curdatetime=curdatetime.replace(':','_').replace(' ','_')


class InputCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
   model = Input_Product
   form_class = InputForm
   template_name = 'inputs/create_product.html'
   success_message = 'Success: Input Product is created.'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('input_product_list')

   def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
      form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user

       # get the image by using request.FILES.get
      filepath = self.request.FILES.get('product_Image', False)
      user_id = self.request.user.id

      #generate filename along with datetime string
      key = base.INPUT_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FOLDER+'/images/' + str(user_id) + '/productimages/' + curdatetime + '.png'

      if filepath == False:
          print(filepath)
      else: #if file exists send the those file and s3 details to upload_to_s3 to upload the data into s3               
          s3status = upload_to_s3(base.S3_KEY, base.S3_SECRET, filepath, base.S3_BUCKET, key, callback=None, md5=None,
                                reduced_redundancy=False, content_type=None)

       # after upload the image, set the filepath value to column(file or image field variable)
       form.instance.product_Image=key
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

> Create utils.py file and declare upload_to_s3 method

```
import os
import boot
from boto.s3.key import Key

def upload_to_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, file, bucket, key, 
          callback=None, md5=None,
             reduced_redundancy=False, content_type=None):
    try:
       size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
    except:
       # Not all file objects implement fileno(),
       # so we fall back on this
       file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
       size = file.tell()

    conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket, validate=True)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = key
    if content_type:
       k.set_metadata('Content-Type', content_type)
    sent = k.set_contents_from_file(file, cb=callback, md5=md5, 
        reduced_redundancy=reduced_redundancy, rewind=True)

    # Rewind for later use
    file.seek(0)

    if sent == size:
       return True
    return False
```